# Safari desktop browser not support geocordinates?

Tags: safari, geolocation, google-api

I'm using this code for get current location Geo codes it work for all other browser except safari why??
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working in Safari desktop browser??

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting->preferences 
in privacy tab ,In  limit website access to  location service choose 1st or 2nd option.